# Getting a list inside a firestore document into a recyclerview

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i have a document inside `firestore`,  that document also has a list inside is called "foods". I want to be able to load only that list of "foods" into a `recyclerview`, I'm not sure how to query the list for recycler options. Here is what the DB structure looks like:

[image]

Here is my **Adapter**

```
   List<Order> myOrders;

    public OrderDetailAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Order> options) {
        super(options);
    }
  
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderDetailAdapter.DetailsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Order model) {
        Order order = myOrders.get(position);

        holder.product_name.setText(model.getProductName());
        holder.product_price.setText(model.getPrice());
        holder.product_quantity.setText(model.getQuantity());
        holder.product_discount.setText(model.getDiscount());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrderDetailAdapter.DetailsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_item_layout, parent,false);
        return new DetailsHolder(v);
    }

    public class DetailsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView product_name, product_price, product_discount, product_quantity;

        public DetailsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            product_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            product_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            product_discount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_discount);
            product_quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myOrders.size();
    }

}
```

Here is my Activity:

```
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference documentReference;

    TextView order_id, order_comment, order_date, order_total;
    String order_id_value ="";
    RecyclerView lstFoods;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    OrderDetailAdapter orderAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_details);

        if (getIntent() !=null)
            order_id_value = getIntent().getStringExtra("order_number");

        documentReference = db.collection("Requests").document(order_id_value);

        lstFoods = findViewById(R.id.food_list);
        lstFoods.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        lstFoods.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        order_id.setText(order_id_value);


        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
              
                    Order order = documentSnapshot.toObject(Order.class);

                    orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lstFoods.setAdapter(orderAdapter);


                }else{
                    Log.d("TAG", "ERROR");
                }

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        orderAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        orderAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

When i try to run it i get the following error:

> error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to FirestoreRecyclerOptions
> super(options);

Comment: Hi Emil. I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)** can help you solve this issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo THank you so much for the resource, i fooled as it is but the problem im getting now when i try to log the list i just get " [com.example.hoastrestaurants.Models.Order@a3bfa9d]" instead of the actual values that i could see when using  List<Map<String, Object>> how can i get the values from the final list we created?

Comment: What you see is the address of the object from the memory. Simply override the toString method or call a method on that object.